# I want to know difference between code status and exe-file status of pyvisa

Tags: pyinstaller

I made a program to controll some instruments like oscilloscope and power supply and so on.
I used pyvisa and pyqt5 and pyinstaller to make a code and Gui.

It worked well in visual studio code before to be exe-file. But it didn't work after being exe-file using pyinstaller.
Exe-file worked well up to the gui screen. And when I pressed the [Setting] button, it connects to various equipment using GPIB. At this time, the GUI is terminated due to an error and stops in the following log.

For the test, I ran this program on two additional computers, one of which had the same symptoms and the other operated well with exe file.
I don't know the difference between a computer that works well and my laptop now.
Please give me some advice on what to confirm.

```
[...]
2023-08-03 19:18:21,329 [   DEBUG] No user defined library files
2023-08-03 19:18:21,329 [   DEBUG] The IVI implementation available
2023-08-03 19:18:21,331 [   DEBUG] No user defined configuration
2023-08-03 19:18:21,356 [   DEBUG] Automatically found library files: [None, 'C:\\windows\\system32\\visa32.dll', 'C:\\windows\\system32\\visa32.dll', 'C:\\windows\\system32\\visa64.dll', 'C:\\windows\\system32\\visa64.dll']
2023-08-03 19:18:21,358 [   DEBUG] No user defined library files
2023-08-03 19:18:21,423 [   DEBUG] Library signatures: 90 ok, 0 failed
2023-08-03 19:18:21,423 [   DEBUG] Created library wrapper for C:\windows\system32\visa32.dll
2023-08-03 19:18:21,426 [   DEBUG] viOpenDefaultRM('<ViObject object at 0x00000239590416D0>',) -> -1073807202
```

I ran the same program on two additional computers, and confirmed that one showed the same phenomenon and the other operated normally.

Since there is a computer that operates normally, there is no problem with my code and I think it is a problem due to some setting difference.
However, I do not know what to check because the newly downloaded computer of Ni-Visa and Python shows the same phenomenon.